# optimize hive query for multitable join

Tags: join, hadoop, amazon-web-services, query-optimization, hive

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE result
SELECT /*+ STREAMTABLE(product) */
i.IMAGE_ID, 
p.PRODUCT_NO,
p.STORE_NO,
p.PRODUCT_CAT_NO,
p.CAPTION,
p.PRODUCT_DESC,
p.IMAGE1_ID,
p.IMAGE2_ID, 
s.STORE_ID, 
s.STORE_NAME, 
p.CREATE_DATE, 
CASE WHEN custImg.IMAGE_ID is NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 
CASE WHEN custImg1.IMAGE_ID is NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 
CASE WHEN custImg2.IMAGE_ID is NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM image i  
JOIN PRODUCT p ON i.IMAGE_ID = p.IMAGE1_ID
JOIN PRODUCT_CAT pcat ON p.PRODUCT_CAT_NO = pcat.PRODUCT_CAT_NO
JOIN STORE s ON p.STORE_NO = s.STORE_NO
JOIN STOCK_INFO si ON si.STOCK_INFO_ID = pcat.STOCK_INFO_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMIZABLE_IMAGE custImg ON i.IMAGE_ID = custImg.IMAGE_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMIZABLE_IMAGE custImg1 ON p.IMAGE1_ID = custImg1.IMAGE_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMIZABLE_IMAGE custImg2 ON p.IMAGE2_ID = custImg2.IMAGE_ID;
```

I have a join query where i am joining huge tables and i am trying to optimize this hive query. Here are some facts about the tables

image table has 60m rows, 
product table has 1b rows, 
product_cat has 1000 rows, 
store has 1m rows, 
stock_info has 100 rows, 
customizable_image has 200k rows.

a product can have one or two images (image1 and image2) and product level information are stored only in product table. i tried moving the join with product to the bottom but i couldnt as all other following joins require data from the product table.

Here is what i tried so far, 
1. I gave the hint to hive to stream product table as its the biggest one
2. I bucketed the table (during create table) into 256 buckets (on image_id) and then did the join - didnt give me any significant performance gain
3. changed the input format to sequence file from textfile(gzip files) , so that it can be splittable and hence more mappers can be run if hive want to run more mappers

Here are some key logs from hive console. I ran this hive query in aws. Can anyone help me understand the primary bottleneck here ? This job is only processing a subset of the actual data.

```
Stage-14 is selected by condition resolver.
Launching Job 1 out of 11
Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 22
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapred.reduce.tasks=<number>
Kill Command = /home/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_201403242034_0001
Hadoop job information for Stage-14: number of mappers: 341; number of reducers: 22
2014-03-24 20:55:05,709 Stage-14 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
.
2014-03-24 23:26:32,064 Stage-14 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 34198.12 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 0 days 9 hours 29 minutes 58 seconds 120 msec
.
2014-03-25 00:33:39,702 Stage-30 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 20879.69 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 0 days 5 hours 47 minutes 59 seconds 690 msec
.
2014-03-26 04:15:25,809 Stage-14 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 3903.4 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 0 days 1 hours 5 minutes 3 seconds 400 msec
.
2014-03-26 04:25:05,892 Stage-30 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 2707.34 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 45 minutes 7 seconds 340 msec
.
2014-03-26 04:45:56,465 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 3901.99 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 0 days 1 hours 5 minutes 1 seconds 990 msec
.
2014-03-26 04:54:56,061 Stage-26 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 2388.71 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 39 minutes 48 seconds 710 msec
.
2014-03-26 05:12:35,541 Stage-4 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 3792.5 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 0 days 1 hours 3 minutes 12 seconds 500 msec
.
2014-03-26 05:34:21,967 Stage-5 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 4432.22 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 0 days 1 hours 13 minutes 52 seconds 220 msec
.
2014-03-26 05:54:43,928 Stage-21 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 6052.96 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 0 days 1 hours 40 minutes 52 seconds 960 msec

MapReduce Jobs Launched: 

Job 0: Map: 59  Reduce: 18   Cumulative CPU: 3903.4 sec     HDFS Read: 37387 HDFS Write: 12658668325 SUCCESS
Job 1: Map: 48              Cumulative CPU: 2707.34 sec   HDFS Read: 12658908810 HDFS Write: 9321506973 SUCCESS
Job 2: Map: 29  Reduce: 10   Cumulative CPU: 3901.99 sec   HDFS Read: 9321641955 HDFS Write: 11079251576 SUCCESS
Job 3: Map: 42              Cumulative CPU: 2388.71 sec   HDFS Read: 11079470178 HDFS Write: 10932264824 SUCCESS
Job 4: Map: 42  Reduce: 12   Cumulative CPU: 3792.5 sec     HDFS Read: 10932405443 HDFS Write: 11812454443 SUCCESS
Job 5: Map: 45  Reduce: 13   Cumulative CPU: 4432.22 sec   HDFS Read: 11812679475 HDFS Write: 11815458945 SUCCESS
Job 6: Map: 42              Cumulative CPU: 6052.96 sec   HDFS Read: 11815691155 HDFS Write: 0 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 days 7 hours 32 minutes 59 seconds 120 msec
OK
```

The query is still taking longer than 5 hours in Hive where as in RDBMS it takes only 5 hrs. I need some help in optimizing this query, so that it executes much faster. Interestingly, when i ran the task with 4 large core instances, the time taken improved only by 10 mins compared to the run with 3 large instance  core instances. but when i ran the task with 3 med cores, it took 1hr 10 mins more.

This brings me to the question, "is Hive even the right choice for such complex joins" ?

Comment: Is your table partitioned anywhere?

Comment: no, its not partitioned now. I read that partitioning helps with where queries but didnt read anywhere about join queries. Anyways, I am planning to try partitioning the table with image_id.

Comment: yes..once you partition you can use various options like `DISTRIBUTE BY` and `CLUSTER BY` in your multi join queries to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the bottleneck is just in sorting your product table, since it seems much larger than the others.  I think joins with Hive for tables over a certain size become untenable, simply because they require a sort.

There are parameters to optimize sorting, like io.sort.mb, which you can try setting, so that more sorting occurs in memory, rather than spilling to disk, re-reading and re-sorting. Look at the number of spilled records, and see if this much larger than your inputs.  There are a variety of ways to optimize sorting.  It might also help to break your query up into multiple subqueries so it doesn't have to sort as much at one time.

For the stock_info , and product_cat tables, you could probably keep them in memory since they are so small ( Check out the 'distributed_map' UDF in Brickhouse ( https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/blob/master/src/main/java/brickhouse/udf/dcache/DistributedMapUDF.java )  For custom image, you might be able to use a bloom filter, if having a few false positives is not a real big problem.

To completely remove the join, perhaps you could store the image info in a keystone DB like HBase to do lookups instead. Brickhouse also had UDFs for HBase , like hbase_get and base_cached_get .

Comment: I will try the sort setting you suggested. Are you recommending to join product and image in one query and join the rest using some in-memory method ? I thought hive already does MapJoin (for smaller tables) which is an in-memory join, isnt it ? I am trying to find the bottleneck by looking at the hive console output from aws. I had no success in infering any useful information from it. I will edit the question with that info, in the hope that someone can help me catch the bottleneck.